# How to return a unique element from a C# array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

**Problem**

I am trying to return a unique element from a C# array with the in-built method `array.Distinct.First()`. The method works for some arrays but returns an incorrect element for this array `{11,11,11,14,11,11}`. It gives me an output of `11` which is incorrect because the unique element in that array is supposed to `14`.
I know there is a way to do that with a `predicate` function but that is just the reason why am asking, I do not know

**Code**

```
public static int getUnique(IEnumerable<int> numbers){
return numbers.Distinct().First();
//you can bet i tried .FirstOrDefault()
//without any success
}
```

Any help to make that code return the correct value is highly appreciated.

Comment: That's not what [distinct does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0)

Comment: What should it return in the scenario where `{11,11,11,14,11,12}`, etc?

Comment: `array.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x =>x.Count() == 1).First()`

Comment: Okay, i need to see more of the C# docs, i thought it returns a unique element for the array. It also returns unique elements for other arrays per se

Comment: @Liam, 14 and 12

Answer (score 3):

That's not what [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) does.

It'll return distinct elements from a sequence, thus removing the duplicates.

You only want the items that have no duplicates to begin with;

```
var numbers = new int[] { 11, 11, 11, 14, 11 };

foreach (var i in numbers.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

You obviously want the first non-duplicate value, so you'd get something like this;

```
var numbers = new int[] { 11, 11, 11, 14, 11 };
    
int? firstNonDuplicate = numbers.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();
    
Console.WriteLine(firstNonDuplicate);
```

Be vary of your null checks here though, this just proves a point.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, can you edit to make it assign the predicate result to a single int variable which is easier to return

Comment: There you go, @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU

Answer (score 2):

using distinct it will return all distinct element. Get a unique value in following way

```
int[] numbers = { 11, 11, 11, 14, 11 };
            Console.WriteLine(numbers.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key).First());
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you should group your collection by a key and then filter that by the number of containing elements:

```
var groupings=  numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Now that gives you *all* unique numbers. Your question is a bit vague, because you want "a" unique number - not "the" unique number, so there is room for interpretation, what should happen, if there are multiple numbers.

Option 1: Just take the first result:

```
var uniques = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Key)
                       .First();
```

Option 1.1 Order results and take the smallest (or largest)

```
var uniques = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Key)
                       .OrderBy(x => x)
                       .First();
```

Option 2: Ensure there is only one unique number and throw otherwise:

```
var uniques = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                       .Select(x => x.Key)
                       .Single();
```

Be aware: If there are no unique numbers, `Single()` and `First()` will throw, where as `SingleOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault()` will return the default value of `int`, which is `0`, which can lead to false results. You can consider changing it to `int?` to allow for `null` to be returned, if there are no unique numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
    var numbers = new int[] { 11, 11, 11, 14, 11, 11 };
    var uniqueList = numbers.GroupBy(n => n).Where(item => item.Count() == 1).Select(item => item.Key);

    foreach (var item in uniqueList)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a special method for you. I approached the subject somewhat primitively. Thanks to this method, you can easily find unique variables.

```
public static int[] getUniqiue(int[] vs)
        {
            List<int> vs1 = new List<int>(vs);
            List<int> vs2 = new List<int>(vs);
            List<int> ee = new List<int>();
            List<int> vs3 = new List<int>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in vs1)
            {
                vs2.Remove(item);
                if(vs3.Contains(item) || vs2.Contains(item))
                {
                    vs3.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    ee.Add(item);
                }
                i++;
            }
            return ee.ToArray();
        }
```